# how to write comma separated list items to csv in a single column in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a list(fulllist) of 292 items and converted to data frame. Then tried writing it to csv in python.

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.DataFrame(fulllist)
my_df.to_csv('Desktop/pgm/111.csv', index=False,sep=',')
```

But the some comma separated values fills each columns of csv. I am trying to make that values in single column. 
Portion of output is shown below.

[image]

I have tried with `writerows` but wont work.

```
import csv
with open('Desktop/pgm/111.csv', "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(fulllist)
    writer.writerows(fulllist)
```

Also tried with `"".join` at each time, when the length of list is higher than 1. It also not giving the result. How to make the proper csv so that each fields fill each columns?
My expected output csv is
[image]

Comment: `I am trying to make that values in single cell.` CSV files don't have "cells". Please clarify your question, e.g. with expected output and current output *shown* via an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54144765/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that `.csv` files are in fact plain text files and understanding of `.csv` by given software depends on implementation, for example some might allow newline  character as part of field, when it is between `"` and `"`, while other treat every newline character as next row.

Do you have to use `.csv` format? If not consider other possibilities:

DSV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values is similiar to csv, but you can use for example `;` instead of `,`, which should help if you do not have `;` in your data

`openpyxl` allows writing and reading of `.xlsx` files.